# Como agregar acciones diferentes a los botones generados en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas, Estos intentando agregarle una acción a cada botón que se genera con una consulta, como ven hago 3 acciones por cada **items** : *modificar* | *Ver* | *Aprobaciones*.

**En ver son los archivos PDF.**

Como puedo hacer para agregarle una acción a cada botón por cada registro... 
[image: Imagen de consulta]

```
while ($extraido = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

if($extraido['status_final']==0)
{
  $vistos = '<img src="img/novisto.png" height="35" width="35">';
}
if($extraido['status_final']==1 || $extraido['status_final']==2)
{
  $vistos = '<img src="img/visto.png" height="35" width="35">';
}
if($extraido['status_final']==3)
{
  $vistos = '<img src="img/aprob.png" height="35" width="35">';
}
?>  
<tr>
<td><?php echo $extraido['id_prod'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['nom_empre'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['nom_prod'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['f_creacion'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['f_modificacion'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $vistos ?></td>

<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="" id="">Modificar</button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="ver" id="">ver</button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="" id="">Aprobaciones</button></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: te refieres a que el boton **ver** realice una accion , **modificar** otra y **aprobaciones** otra ?

Comment: si, asi mismo. y para cada registro, es decir. si se listan N cantidad de items cada items tiene que tener esas 3 acciones.

Comment: Y que pasa cuando presionas un boton de esos? que debe de mostrar?

Comment: Tienes 3 opciones hacerlo a través de javascript, convertir los botones a submit, ponerles un name y del lado de donde realizas la acción a donde redirecciona validar con que se hizo el submit y de ahí realizar cada acción correspondiente. Convertilo en un <a> y pasarle de parametro el id de cada producto. La última me parece mejor pero eso ya es a tu criterio, después vienes con dudas más puntuales.

Comment: en teoria estoy intentando que el boton modificar me envie a la pagina de subir el archivo, el boton de VER mostrarme el archivo pdf que coresponde
 a su nombre y id, y Aprobaciones a otra pagina

Comment: revisa mi respuesta , dime si no es eso lo que deseas, si es algo especifico o como no mandar una petición y hacer otra cosa dime para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de un botón, podrías utilizar un enlace con forma de botón. Si estás usando Bootstrap, sería una etiqueta así:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Modificar</a>
```

Y en el atributo href pones la página con el id en el [query string](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/modificar.php?id=<?=$extraido['id_prod']?>" role="button">Modificar</a>
```

Y así no tienes que usar javascript, simplemente cambia los botones por estas etiquetas:

```
<td> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/modificar.php?id=<?=$extraido['id_prod']?>" role="button">Modificar</a></td>
//Produce un enlace estilo /modificar.php?id=1 por cada registro que muestres en la tabla
<td> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/ver.php?id=<?=$extraido['id_prod']?>" role="button">Ver</a></td>
<td> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/apro.php?id=<?=$extraido['id_prod']?>" role="button">Aprobaciones</a></td>
```

Es especialmente útil, si solo tienes que abrir otra página. Si piensas realizar acciones más complejas, tendrás que usar Javascript.

Y luego, en tu archivo accion.php puedes obtener el id a través de la variable [$_GET](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) y mostrar lo que tengas que mostrar.

```
<?php
   $prod_id = $_GET['id']; 
   //Ahora puedes usar $prod_id para buscar la información en la base de 
   //datos e imprimirlo en la página. 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, tendrás una lista de archivos **pdf**, y quieres tener arlado ver, modificar y aprobaciones y que cuando le des a alguno de esos botones realice esa acción para ese **pdf**, en ese caso cambiariamos par de cosas para agilizar, quedaría así:

```
<tr id="documentos"> //le agrego un id a los tr para poder acceder al evento click dentro de el
<td><?php echo $extraido['id_prod'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['nom_empre'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['nom_prod'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['f_creacion'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $extraido['f_modificacion'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $vistos ?></td>

//a cada boton le agrego como id el id_prod mas -mod si es modificar, -ver si es ver , y -apro si es aprobaciones
<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="" id="<?php $extraido['id_prod']."-mod" ?>">Modificar</button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="ver" id="<?php $extraido['id_prod']."-ver" ?>">ver</button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="" id="<?php $extraido['id_prod']."-apro" ?>">Aprobaciones</button></td>
</tr>
```

luego con javascript, manejo la pulsaciones de los botones, y mando la petición al server con el id del producto y la acción, **quedaría así:**

```
//importando jquery
$('#documentos button').click(function(){
    var id_doc = $(this).prop('id').split('-')[0] // aqui capturo el id_prod que se selecciono la accion
    var ruta = '',accion='';

    if($(this).prop('id').split('-')[1] == 'ver'){ 
       ruta = '/ver',accion='ver'
    }else if($(this).prop('id').split('-')[1] == 'apro'){
       ruta = '/aproba',accion='aprobaciones'
    } else if($(this).prop('id').split('-')[1] == 'mod'){
       ruta = '/mod',accion='modificar'
    }
   if(accion == 'ver'){ //si la acción es ver redirijo a esa ruta sino hago la petición.
      location.href = '/visor.php?id_p' + id_doc // aqui cuando es accion ver envio a visor.php pasandole en la ruta en la variable id_p el id del documento    
   }else{

       $.ajax({
         url:ruta,
         type:'POST', // puede ser POST o GET , eso depende de lo que esperes en el servidor
         data:{ id_producto:id_doc, accion:accion}, // enviando al server por ejemplo, a la ruta /ver un json { id_producto:5698, accion: 'modificar' }
        }).done(function(data){ //el .done es por si envías datos del servidor luego de cumplir la petición , y si mandas información viene en data.
         console.log('Datos:',data)

       })
   }
})
```

Comment: estoy tratando de implementar tu codigo pero da error en -mod -ver -apro, lo coloque con ' ' " ", pero no ejecutan las acciones, en ver le estoy colocando para ir a visor.php y no hace nada.. :/

Comment: por ejemplo cada vez que des en ver , pasarias a **/visor.php** , pero supongo que devez enviar a esa ruta por get el id_prod , para saber cual mostrar en el visor , entonces la ruta seria **/visor.php?id_p=a12** por ejemplo es eso , dime para actualizar la respuesta

Comment: correcto eso es lo que trato de hacer, que al darle click. me lleve a visor.php con su respectivo id para generar una consulta.

Comment: ok, deja actualizar la respuesta , enviando el id por el get en la ruta

Comment: encontre un error , pera ahora mismo te actualizo con todo ok, es que encontre un espacio que cojia de mas como , y adicione .split(' ')[0]

Comment: no entiendo porque no hace nada... estoy metiendo en <script type="javascript"> </script> el codigo js. y si le coloque ' ' " " a -ver sino da error.. las coloque asi.  ´id="<?php echo $extraido['id_prod'].'-mod' ?>´      ´id="<?php echo $extraido['id_prod']."-mod" ?>´

Comment: ya te actualice la respuesta otra vez, discúlpame tenia errores que ayer no me fije, lo del **.split(' ')[0]** que agregue quitalo fue un error, le adicione **" "** a los **-ver , -mod , ...** , e importante cuando pongo los id se tiene que quitar los **echo** que no me fije, a la vez que los quitas entonces si se ponen bien los id, prueba ahora con estos cambios